# Problem black screen with Lubuntu in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I installed a Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (and a v.17) both architectures x86 and 64 bits.

The problem is when I shut down the Virtual Lubuntu (installed) then, sometimes runs ok but one of them, the machine shows how is starting Lubuntu, but only shows an black screen. I can't do anything. I tried several times and I got always the same problem.

It was working fine the same machine I was working since 1 month and I never get this problem...

[image]

Comment: Same problem for me. Any progress?

Answer (score -1):

(This is just a guess.)

After upgrading to VirtualBox 5.2.6-120293, I started getting the same «black screen».

Disabling «3D acceleration» and «2D video acceleration» (virtual machine «Settings» => «Display» tab => «Screen» sub-tab) has helped.